# How to add Element in te combo box in loop, QML, Sailfish, Sailfish OS

Tags: qml

I have a python function that returns a list, with Python, I can get the list, but I don't know how to add that list to qml for sailfish os. code example

```
menu: ContextMenu {
    id: cntmenu
    onClicked : test()
    MenuItem { "text: option a" }
    MenuItem { text: "option b" }
    MenuItem { text: "option c" }
    .... etc
}
functiontest(){
    var testArray=[]
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
        testArray.append({"text":"Item" + i})
        console.log(i)
    }
    return testArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. But as I understand you want to fill in entries in a combo box.

Following code would fill in entries into a ListModel and add this model to a ComboBox:

```
function fillModel() {
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        model1.append({"key": "Item " + i, "value" : i});
    }
}

ComboBox {
    id: combo1
    textRole: "key"

    Component.onCompleted: fillModel();
    model: ListModel {
        id: model1
    }

}
```